# Order Link List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a base class called linkList and two derived class. One order link list class and unorder link list class. My order link list class is not working and i have no idea why.When i insert 3 numbers into the list it work but when i insert more than 4 values it messes up. It will also say the length of the list is larger than what it actually is. [enter image description here][1]

```
void insert(const T& newItem){
    nodeType<T> *current;
    nodeType<T> *trailCurrent=nullptr;
    nodeType<T> *newNode;

    bool found;

    newNode = new nodeType<T>;
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    //if the list is empty add to empty list
    if (this->first == nullptr){
        this->first = newNode;
        this->last = newNode;
        this->count++;
    }
    else {

        current = this->first;
        found = false;

        while (current != nullptr && !found){
            if (current->info >= newItem)
                found = true;
            else{
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->next;
            }

            //if current value is first item into the list insert into the front
            if (current == this->first){
                newNode->next = this->first;
                this->first=newNode;
                this->count++;

            }
            else{

                trailCurrent->next = newNode;
                newNode->next=current;

                if (current == nullptr)
                    this->last = newNode;

                this->count++;

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is an unordered list?

Comment: "It messes up" -- How is it messing up? What is happening?

Comment: nvm i found the error ! Thats crazy after starring at it all nigh i figure it out as soon as i post a question. It messes up because my while loop contain al the nested if-else statements ! The while loop should only be for the first if-else statement. Prolly explain it bad @picklechips

Comment: i also started creating a class called intLinkedList that split a list inot two parts, even and odd. My code gets stuck into a continue loop. Can anyone spot where my code goes wrong ?

Comment: Five bucks says that the debugging program that probably came with your development environment will help you pin down the infinite loop within a couple minutes. If your development environment doesn't have a debugger, do yourself a huge favour and get an environment that does.